# Is it safe to share SKU publicly?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-security

[Documentation states](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview):

> A purchase token is a string that represents a buyer's entitlement to
>   a product on Google Play. It indicates that a Google user has paid for
>   a specific product, represented by a SKU

and

> Product ID - A unique, human readable ID for your product. Product IDs
>   are also called SKUs in the Google Play Billing Library.

As it is human readable I believe we can share SKU publicly (ex. in deeplinks).

Do we leak anything for hackers in that case or should we hash SKU?

Answer (score 1):

> As it is human readable I believe we can share SKU publicly (ex. in deeplinks).

Yes you can use them wherever you like, even if the product is only accessible by who bought it or have permissions to see it.

As you say, it is public, therefore not a secret and does not have any authorization capabilities.

> Do we leak anything for hackers in that case or should we hash SKU?

No need to hash the SKU once it is public information that by itself cannot allow an hacker to have access to the purchased product. The hacker will need to have access to the purchase token and maybe other credentials to be able to access the product in the same way as the one who purchased it.

Before I go please allow me for a quick alert...

It may be seen as obvious but the **purchase token** must be considered as a **secret**, therefore it must be kept safe at all times, but this is not an easy task to achieve.

Please keep in mind that any tokens you have inside your app source code are easily extracted with reverse engineer techniques as I point out in [this blog post](https://blog.approov.io/is-your-mobile-app-leaking-secrets):

> Oh and did I mention already that in the case of mobile apps their binaries may be reverse engineered with tools like the Mobile Security Framework despite some techniques you may have employed to protect the secrets in your mobile app at run-time or to hide them from being reverse engineered from your binary?

As I point out on that blog post more advanced users can also use reverse engineer techniques to extract tokens at runtime with tools like the [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF). More tools can be found by searching on google for `dynamic instrumentation tools`.